# How to link to an answer at community.office365.com

Tags: links, office-365

[community.office365.com](http://community.office365.com) is Microsoft's microsofty attempt at a QA site.

Among other astonishing problems, I can't find an easy way to link to an answer.
On StackExchange I would click on `share`, and that would give the link, for me to copy.
There, when I click on `Share`, the arrow starts flipping, but apart from this nothing special seems to happen (Firefox).

For instance, how to easily copy the direct URL to the first answer of [this question](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/148/t/151507.aspx)? (Edward's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this in Firefox 15.0.1 and Chrome 30.0.1599.101 (both on Mac):

- Click the share link
- Click the email option
- Copy the link at the top of the window that pops up

Currently, this link does include the fragment identifier to go to that specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not user-friendly, but here is the only solution I have found so far:

- CTRL-C part of the answer
- CTRL-U to see the HTML code
- CTRL-F CTRL-V to find the HTML code for the answer
- Scroll up until you see `<a name="424353"></a>`
- Add the number to the URL like http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/148/p/151507/424259.aspx#424353

Note: The Share link does not work on Firefox, but on Opera it shows in all its horror: No direct URL, all options force you to log into a social network, except the email option which shows an URL that does NOT link to the answer but to the whole question. In clear, it is unusable and looking at the HTML source seems to be the only solution.